# How can I take just a part of CSS from other site's when using bootstrap?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have the website using bootstrap for its css style.
What if I want to take just a little bit of part of css from other website?
What would be the best way?  I tried to use one of the function 'inspection' with Firefox.
It shows all the hierarchy and its styles stated for each class.

The thing I really care about is confliction between bootstrap and the new css.
How would you guys solve this if you want to take just a little bit part of other css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't pick up styles from other's website before a prior permission from the site administrator...

For the bootstrap..I've never used it but still according to me you can over-ride the default bootstrap styles by using CSS [!important](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

> I tried to use one of the function 'inspection' with Firefox. It shows
>   all the hierarchy and its styles stated for each class.

Styling a single element is never dependent on a single class, it inherits some of the properties from the parent class too...For example

```
<style>
.wrapper {
   color: #ff0000;
}

.hello {
   background-color: #aaaaaa;
   / *Width and color of the parent div is inherited */
}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="hello">Hello World</div> <!-- So actually this uses color and width of .wrapper and background-color of .hello -->
</div>
```

Comment: than it will use `.hello` color, if you don't specify it will inherit parent container's color, wait I'll show you an example

Comment: This will use red even if you are using `#000000` for `p` http://jsfiddle.net/r8dqc/3/

Comment: @MKK you welcome...also take a look at CSS specificity http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/